# Using linq or plain c# to populate a given object structure

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to populate the AllTerms object that will contain  `LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel`  and `LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel` objects.

Basically the **LEGAL_FUND_CLASS** table has parent and child records and are related by column **LegalParentClassId**. One parent has one child. So I need to loop  through **legalfundClasses** object and populate 
`IEnumerable<LegalFundClassWrapper> AllTerms` . The LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel represents the records in the **LEGAL_FUND_CLASS** table.  So **legalfundClasses** variable contains records from this **legal_fund_class** table. There are several records. Some records wont have child record. I need to populate  in a way where the parent record gets added to **LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel** and its child record gets added to
**LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel**. The wrapper would contain a collection of Parent and child records where some child records wont exist and hence the **LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel** property would be null.

Can somebody give me an idea on how to go about it ?

C#

```
 public class LegalFundClassViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<LegalFundClassWrapper> AllTerms;


        public class LegalFundClassWrapper
        {
            public LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel { get; set; }
            public LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel { get; set; }
        }

    }

    public class LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel
    {

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AuditSummary { get; set; }
        public string FeesReviewSummary { get; set; }
        public string TermsReviewSummary { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FundId { get; set; }
        public int FundClassType { get; set; }
        public int? CurrencyId { get; set; }
        public string PrimaryCurrencyName { get; set; }
        public string OtherCurrencyName { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerStrategyId { get; set; }
        public string ManagerStrategyName { get; set; }
        public int? SubVotingId { get; set; }
        public string SubVotingName { get; set; }
        public int? SubHotIssueId { get; set; }
        public string SubHotIssueName { get; set; }
        public int? RedsFrqncyId { get; set; }
        public string RedsFrqncyName { get; set; }
        public int? RedsNoticeDays { get; set; }
        public int? NoticeTypeOfDaysId { get; set; }
        public string NoticeTypeOfDaysName { get; set; }
        public int? LegalParentClassId { get; set; }
   }

 var managerStrategyFundIds = GetService<MANAGERSTRATEGY>().WhereWithIncludes<MANAGERSTRATEGY>(x => x.ID == managerStratedyId, x => x.FUNDs).SelectMany(x => x.FUNDs).Select(x => x.ID).ToList();  

var legalfundClasses = GetService<LEGAL_FUND_CLASS>().Where(x => managerStrategyFundIds.Contains(x.FUND_ID));
```

What I was trying creates a list of all the records in one. How do I loop through and populate the AllTerms

```
  var allFunds = legalfundClasses.Select(fc => new LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel
        {
            Description = fc.DESCRIPTION,
            Id = fc.ID,
            FundId = fc.FUND_ID,
            FundClassType = fc.CLASS_TYPE,
            AuditSummary = getAuditSummary(managerStratedyId, fc.ID),
            FeesReviewSummary = getFeesReviewSummary(fc),
            TermsReviewSummary = getTermsReviewSummary(fc),
            CurrencyId = fc.CURRENCY_ID,
        });



public class LegalFundClassViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<LegalFundClassWrapper> AllTerms;


        public class LegalFundClassWrapper
        {
            public LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel 
         LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel { get; set; }
            public LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel 
          LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel { get; set; }
        }
```

As you can see in the image below, there are two records. The record that has value in legal_parent_class id field is the child to the record on top of it. If you notice the id of the top record matches the bottom record's legal_parent_class_id.

What is the best way to identify the child and store records in respective properties accordingly

[image]

Comment: Well, until you tell us in detail and **accurately** how a particular _LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel_ instance should be assigned to either the _LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel_ or _LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel_ property of your _LegalFundClassWrapper_, it will be impossible for us to make meaningful suggestions.

Comment: i haven't understant from where you get managerStrategyFundIds

Comment: I shall update my post now.

Comment: Let me know if my post  update is clear. As I mentioned I need to add the parent record to LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel and child record to LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel

Comment: Do I need to put conditional statement snd how do I check . The parent record generally has null value in the legal_parent_class_id field and the child record has the id of the parent in that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins). In your case

```
var allFunds = new[]
{
    new LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel
    {
        Id = 101,
        Description = "Parent with child"
    },
    new LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel
    {
        Id = 102,
        Description = "Parent without child"
    },
    new LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel
    {
        Id = 103,
        Description = "I'm child",
        LegalParentClassId = 101
    }
};

var allTerms = (from fund in allFunds
                where fund.LegalParentClassId == null //only parents
                join child in allFunds on fund.Id equals child.LegalParentClassId into gj
                from child2 in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new LegalFundClassViewModel.LegalFundClassWrapper { LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel = fund, LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel = child2 })
            .ToArray();
```